# dockerize NestJS and TypeORM

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs

i have this Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

and docker-compose.yml looks like that :

```
version: '3.1'

services:

      db:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
      node:
        build: .
        volumes:
          - ./public/storage/files:/usr/app/public/storage/files
        env_file: .env
        restart: always
        ports:
          - '8080:8080'
```

When projects starts it uses `ormconfig.json`

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "database": "postgres",
  "password": "root",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity.js"]
}
```

But i have error when run it in docker

```
[Nest] 30   - 08/19/2020, 5:49:39 PM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)... +3003ms
node_1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

Help pls to fix it. Without docker it works perfectly.

Comment: Does postgres image start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you use docker-compose they are not in each other localhost.

Actually they are in separate docker networks

so you have to set their network to a same network or calling them by their `container_name`

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "db", // container name
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "database": "postgres",
  "password": "root",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity.js"]
}
```

A working example is shown below:
*Also mind that its not necessary to do networking manually as @Charles Desbiens said in comments*

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  # Databases # #
  postgresql-test:
    container_name: postgresql-test
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-admin}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-changeme}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-crud-node}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    ports:
      - 30001:5432
    networks:
      - test
...
  node:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: backend:latest
    container_name: backend
    depends_on:
      - postgresql-test
    networks:
      - test
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229

...
networks:
  test:
```

Now you can use  `address: postgresql-test & port: 5432` to access your `db` inside your code

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "postgresql-test",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "admin",
  "database": "crud-node",
  "password": "changeme",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity.js"]
}
```

ALSO you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/golkhandani/nest_boilerplate_sql) repo.

Comment: You don't need to manually create a network and assign the services to it. You also don't need to rename the postgres service. Docker compose automatically creates a default network for all the services in a file and assigns the services to it. So, OP would just have to change the address he's using to connect to the database from 127.0.0.1 to db.

Comment: @MohamadrezaRahimianGolkhandani thanks it works, could you tell me pls, why we have to define ports twice 
`ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229`

Comment: your welcome,
actually 9229 is the default debugger port for debugging nodejs with vscode, so it's better to expose this port in case of you want to debug your app inside container